# Choose a specific network among multiple networks

Tags: openstack, cloudify

I am using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse.

I would like to attach the Cloudify Management VM to two private networks:

**private-net-1** and **private-net-2**

The Cloudify Shell, however, is attached only to **private-net-1**.

So, how should I configure che cloud driver so that the bootstrap-cloud process will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cloudify shell just needs access to the Cloud API. It does not matter if it is connected to one network or more. It is not related to how the Cloudify Manager is set up.

The Cloudify compute template configuration allows you to specify static networks that the compute machine will connect to. See example here:
http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/clouddrivers/network.html

Note this section:

```
  // Optional. Use existing networks.
    computeNetwork {
      networks (["SOME_INTERNAL_NETWORK"])
    }
```

So you can specify multiple networks here:

```
  // Optional. Use existing networks.
    computeNetwork {
      networks (["SOME_INTERNAL_NETWORK1", "SOME_INTERNAL_NETWORK2"])
    }
```

Comment: I have figured out that the first net specified in the section, is the first that will be used to execute ssh commands.

Comment: Correct. It depends a lot on the VM image you are using. Some images only enable the first vNIV. As a result, you have to set your floating IP to that NIC.